# React Native In App Utils

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm trying to set up payments for an iOS app using https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utilsm, but I'm having a small problem which is that when I load NativeModules it does have the InAppUtils property so this returns undefined:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
  const { InAppUtils } = NativeModules
...
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(InAppUtils
}
```

I installed using both `rnpm install --save react-native-in-app-utils` and `npm install --save react-native-in-app-utils; react-native-link`. In both cases it looks like the libraries are linked properly in Xcode.

Any ideas how I can check that the library is installed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed with `yarn add react-native-in-app-utils` and it wasn't working, so I ran `react-native link` and rebuilt the app from XCode and it worked.